# SQL Server 2019 Standard unable to create certificate from 2012 Enterprise backup cert

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2019

I am trying to migrate from SQL Server 2012 Enterprise to SQL Server 2019 Standard and one of my steps involves transferring the TDE cert from 2012 to 2019. I have the cert and key backed up from 2012 and am trying to create a new cert on 2019 using the 2012 key and cert.

This is the same process I use to restore the encryption cert to a new instance of SQL Server 2012. I am getting the following message however when trying to do this same process in SQL Server 2019 Std:

> The certificate, asymmetric key, or private key file is not valid or does not exist; or you do not have permissions for it.

Here is my SQL statement for restoring the cert using a backup of the cert and key:

```
CREATE CERTIFICATE TDECert_SQL2019 
    FROM FILE = 'E:\Backup\TDECert_SQL2019.BAK' 
    WITH PRIVATE KEY (FILE = 'E:\Backup\TDEkey_SQL2019.bkey',
    DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'MYSECUREPASSWORD');  
GO
```

I know the file path is correct and I know the password is correct. I can run this same SQL on a SQL Server 2012 instance with no issues.

I know that SSL certs are dealt with a little differently on SQL Server 2019, but I am not aware of changes with regards to TDE.

Comment: Sounds like the SQL Server service account doesn't have access to the file. I also *assume* `E:` is a storage device on the server, and not a mapped drive?

Comment: It is a partitioned drive.  I had already opened the security on the file to Everyone for Read access when I first got the error.  Also, I can perform the same operation using the SQL 2012 instance on the same machine.

Comment: Do you have a master key? See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-certificate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks

Comment: You sound ensure that the SQL Server service account is specifically named, rather than using `Everyone`. Especially if you haven't configured an AD account for the Service Account.

Comment: To rule out this being a file permissions issue, can you try creating the certificate from binary? I wrote a post on how to export certificates in that format here: http://www.spartansql.com/2015/09/createing-certificate-from-binary-redux.html. It will generate TSQL that should be able to re-create the certificate on a target server.

Comment: It was a file permissions issue.  I had to add NT Server\MSSQLServer and then it imported fine